# Leaflet and MBtiles rendering using Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I would like to render a map with Leaflet from a MBTiles file using the `Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles` library. I added the MBTiles file on the same folder with index.php. I am NOT using a web server like Apache etc. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sql.js@0.3.2/js/sql.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.tilelayer.mbtiles@latest/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js"></script>

    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #map {
        /* configure the size of the map */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // initialize Leaflet
    

    var mb = L.tileLayer.mbTiles('demo.mbtiles').addTo(map);
 
    var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 0, lat: 0}, 2);

      // show the scale bar on the lower left corner
      L.control.scale({imperial: true, metric: true}).addTo(map);

      // show a marker on the map
      L.marker({lon: 0, lat: 0}).bindPopup('The center of the world').addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Regarding the path of the file, I tried also absolute path like `/home/username/Desktop/maps/demo.mbtiles` etc.

Here is the library:
https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles

Comment: What do you see in browser debugger console and network section?

Comment: I can see these messages in Console:
GET https://unpkg.com/leaflet.tilelayer.mbtiles@latest/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
leafletmbtiles.html:31 Uncaught TypeError: L.tileLayer.mbTiles is not a function
    at leafletmbtiles.html:31:27
And under network:404 Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js

Comment: If you type address https://unpkg.com/leaflet.tilelayer.mbtiles@latest/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js directly into the browser, you'll get response: _Cannot find package leaflet.tilelayer.mbtiles@latest_. You'll have to find the right address for the plugin or download it and load it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to capital letters => `https://unpkg.com/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles@1.0.0/Leaflet.TileLayer.MBTiles.js`